# Is Mac OS X 10.7 Lion developer preview 2 stable enough for day to day use?

Tags: developer-program, macos

Is Mac OS X 10.7 Lion developer preview 2 stable enough for day to day use, including using XCode 4?

Comment: See also a Lifehacker article on [How to Update to Mac OS X Lion Without Losing Your Current Installation](http://lifehacker.com/#!5790714/how-to-update-to-mac-os-x-lion-without-losing-your-current-installation)

Comment: I´m sorry, but I had to downvote this question, as I don´t think Lion discussions belong here. Please also see this meta discussion: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399/how-to-handle-lion-questions

Comment: As a third party developer I have to agree that asking questions of this nature asks people to break their NDAs with Apple. Please either join the dev program and ask in the appropriate venues or wait. Sorry to be a spoil sport here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This answer is encumbered by the NDA. Sorry!)

I'm a iOS programming student using 10.7 and Xcode 4.1 on a daily basis, so I'd say yes. Some apps don't work too well and/or crash spectacularly on startup, but it's livable.

I use a second hard drive for Lion, where my SuperDrive used to be. I would recommend against installing Lion on my primary hard drive at this point.

One hint though: symlinks are your friend. A lot of my stuff points right back to the same location on my Snow Leopard drive, such as my iTunes library.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had any crash since I installed it on day one, so I would say yes. Developer Preview 1 was a lot more unstable.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to ask if a Developer Preview version of software is safe enough to use, I highly, HIGHLY advise that you don't use it!

Most people avoid first versions of major new releases for all the same reasons. Unique usage bugs, let someone else find them instead of yourself, for your own sake.

---

If you proceed with this "upgrade". For your own sake and everyone elses, please, please, PLEASE have LOTS of backups of ANY content you need. And I do mean lots of backups.

3-2-1:

3 copies (at least)
2 forms of media (at least)
1 offsite (at least)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't upgraded my OS to the dev preview, but I have been using Xcode 4 since it went public.

I was recently at an iOS developers's conference and the consensus, that I agree with, is that Xcode 4 isn't entirely stable, but to upgrade anyway and submit bug reports wherever convenient. Xcode 4 is very different (and whether or not those differences are better or worse is entirely subjective) but it is clear this is the direction Apple is going in, so we might as well get used to it now.

I would not, however, apply that same logic to the OS.